# Replace linebreak in the end of string using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I have JavaScript variable with a string as value like thi

```
var string;
string = "ushjsb\n laKDJV\n";
```

How can I by using regexp delete ONLY the last linebreak?

Comment: `string = string.replace(/\n$/, '')`

Comment: Also, look at [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) as it may also do what you want (in a clearer way).

Comment: What about `string = "ushjsb\n laKDJV\n\n\n";`? Remove one or three linebreaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
string = string.replace(/\n+$/, "")
```